Pandas add column with min from dict
I have a dictionary with items and conversion factors (multiplication). I need to find for each item in df min value from column 'Col1' between converted values from dict.
For ex.: for Item1: 
converted Item5 = 22 * 10 = 220 
converted Item6 = 2 * 100 = 200 
converted Item4 = 205 * 1 = 205 
Min=200


import pandas as pd

data = {'Item1': {'Item5': 10, 'Item6': 100, 'Item4': 1}, 
        'Item2':  {'Item5': 10, 'Item6': 100, 'Item4': 1}, 
        'Item4':  {'Item5': 10, 'Item6': 100, 'Item9': 1}} 

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(data)

df=pd.DataFrame({
            'Col0':['Item1','Item2','Item3','Item4','Item5','Item6'],
            'Col1':[180,250,150,205,22,2],
            'Col2':[190,150,150,200,18,2.5]
            })
print(df)

The result i want:
result=pd.DataFrame({
            'Item':['Item1','Item2','Item3','Item4','Item5','Item6'],
            'Price1':[180,250,150,205,22,2],
            'Price2':[190,150,150,200,18,2.5],
            'Minc_Col1':[200,200,'NaN',200,'NaN','NaN']
            })
print(result)


Here's one approach:
result = df.set_index('Col0')

new_cols = ['Item', 'Price1', 'Price2']

result = (
    result.assign(
        Minc_Col1=(data.mul(data.index.map(result['Col1']), axis=0).min())
    )
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={f'Col{k}': v for k, v in enumerate(new_cols)})
)

Output
    Item  Price1  Price2  Minc_Col1
0  Item1     180   190.0      200.0
1  Item2     250   150.0      200.0
2  Item3     150   150.0        NaN
3  Item4     205   200.0      200.0
4  Item5      22    18.0        NaN
5  Item6       2     2.5        NaN

Explanation

Let's start with assigning your df to result, with 'Col0' as the index (df.set_index).
Next, take data.index and apply df.index.map, passing result['Col1']. This will get us the correct conversion factors.
Now, we use df.mul to multiply data along axis=0 with the factors, and retrieve df.min to get the min value for each column (your ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item4']).
Assign the resulting Series with df.assign.
The rest is cosmetic: apply df.reset_index and rename your columns with  df.rename.

Intermediates
data.index.map(result['Col1'])
# Index([22.0, 2.0, 205.0, nan], dtype='float64')

# aligned with:
data.index

# Index(['Item5', 'Item6', 'Item4', 'Item9'], dtype='object')

# multiplication with `data` on `axis=0`
data.mul(data.index.map(result['Col1']), axis=0)

       Item1  Item2  Item4
Item5  220.0  220.0  220.0 # (3x) 10 * 22
Item6  200.0  200.0  200.0 # (3x) 100 * 2
Item4  205.0  205.0    NaN # (2x) 1 * 205
Item9    NaN    NaN    NaN # (1x) 1 * NaN

# `min` per column, map by assignment, items not present will get `NaN`
data.mul(data.index.map(result['Col1']), axis=0).min()

Item1    200.0
Item2    200.0
Item4    200.0
dtype: float64


Edit: How to retain the item(s) that source the min?
Option 1 (only first matching item)
Use df.agg with idxmin and min, transpose with df.T, and join with pd.concat on axis=1. Rename column names with method used above.
result = df.set_index('Col0')

m = data.mul(data.index.map(result['Col1']), axis=0).agg(['idxmin', 'min']).T

pd.concat([result, m], axis=1)

       Col1   Col2 idxmin    min
Item1   180  190.0  Item6  200.0
Item2   250  150.0  Item6  200.0
Item3   150  150.0    NaN    NaN
Item4   200  200.0  Item6  200.0
Item5    22   18.0    NaN    NaN
Item6     2    2.5    NaN    NaN

Option 2 (all matching items, in case of ties)

Get multiplication result and df.stack, assign m.
Select from m only where m equals m.min().
Chain df.reset_index and apply df.groupby with groupby.agg and get list for the items and min for the value.
Join to result with pd.concat.

df.loc[df['Col0'].eq('Item4'), 'Col1'] = 200
# Item4 will now also produce `200` for `Item1, Item2`

result = df.set_index('Col0')

m = data.mul(data.index.map(result['Col1']), axis=0).stack()

m = (
    m[m == m.min()]
    .reset_index()
    .groupby('level_1')
    .agg(Item=('level_0', list), Min=(0, 'min'))
)

pd.concat([result, m], axis=1)

       Col1   Col2            Item    Min
Item1   180  190.0  [Item6, Item4]  200.0
Item2   250  150.0  [Item6, Item4]  200.0
Item3   150  150.0             NaN    NaN
Item4   200  200.0         [Item6]  200.0 # 'Item4' absent from list
Item5    22   18.0             NaN    NaN
Item6     2    2.5             NaN    NaN

Decide what you want to do with the lists in added column 'Item'. E.g.,

Join them into a string: change list to lambda x: ','.join(x.unique()).
Or use df.explode to get separate rows: use pd.concat([result, m], axis=1).explode('Item').


Nice one. Alternative without setting the index: df['Min_Col1'] = df['Col0'].map(data.mul(data.index.map(df.set_index('Col0')['Col1']), axis=0).min())

Both answers work perfect! Thank You a lot! Can I ask one more question? How to add column with name of min Item? (Item6 for [0] etc)

Edited the answer to show how you can add the item(s). For future reference, please think very carefully about your desired output in full before posting your question. As you can see, the procedure to get this output is quite a bit different, and the issue of duplicates is to be taken into account.
